# How to connect to WiFi network using Python?

Tags: python, wifi

I am trying to write a script in Python which will enable me to search for wireless networks and to connect to them. Is there any Python library for this?

Comment: you coud try [python-wicd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python-wicd)

Comment: This may well be what you're looking for: https://wifi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: None of the answers below will work on every operating system because the interfaces are too different. You'll have to specify which operating system you're using.

Comment: Here is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662351/connect-wifi-with-python-or-linux-terminal