# Python code for WiFi scanning - error recieved

Tags: python-3.x

i get an error in line 4 and i dont understand why. iam new to python and used an existing code.
the error says : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
import subprocess

results = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"])
results = results.replace("\r", "")

ls = results.split("\n")
ls = ls[4:]

ssids = [] #there we will store our ssids
x = 0
y = 0

while x < len(ls):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        ssids.append(ls[x])
    x += 1

while y < len(ssids):
    print (ssids[y])
    y += 1
```

i want to get a list of all the wifi hosts around

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662351/connect-wifi-with-python-or-linux-terminal

Comment: Thanks , your code looks great.but i need it to print all of the hosts around my location