# Is there code I can run in a program to connect to secured wifi with a known password

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi clock that gets the current time using wifi. It is a gift for my girlfriend so I'd just like to hand it over so she can plug it in and it'll work. I have the SSID and the password for her wifi so is there anyway I can get the clock program to check for wifi and then enter the credentials and after its connected to continue with the program?

Either that or is there a way to attempt to get access to the wifi on boot independent of the program?

Comment: A similiar question can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662351/connect-wifi-with-python-or-linux-terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can install `wireless-tools` on your linux distribution. Executing system command from Python script can do further work, mentioning system commands.

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid WIFI_NETWORK_HERE key s:PASSWORD_HERE
//only works with access points that use WEP as encryption
```

Comment: I'll give it a go tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Under Network Options you will find the WiFi setup.

It might throw some errors because (I assume) you're not in range of the network while setting it up, but should save the settings anyway (I never tried configuring WiFi on the RPi while actually away from the network). Next time it's booted within range of the network, it should auto-connect.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way I know of would be editing the wpa_supplicant.conf, so in the pi;

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and add

```
network={
        ssid="testing"
        psk="testingPassword"
    }
```

More info can be found here;

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md