# How to connect to wifi using python 3 on windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.6

So, I wanted to be able to connect to a network that I know the name and the password, but do not have the profile, and wanted to be able to connect to it in a simple python script. Is there a way I can create an xml profile to use `netsh wlan connect name='profile_name'`? Or another to be able to connect given the network name and the password?

Thanks!

Comment: is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336184/how-to-connect-to-wifi-network-using-python what you're looking for?

Comment: I did take a look at that question... unfortunately, I haven't bee able to use the library in question properly, the documentation is not very clear, and the project is unmaintained.

Comment: I see. I think that its target is also Linux instead of windows. And this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14079546/5985593

Comment: So, I too think that would be the best way, the problem is, you have to have a profile in windows, written in xml. I do not know the contents of given xml, and wanted to be able to write one with python, which would be easy, should I know what to write.